# Self joining table to select different values

Tags: sql, database, ssms

I have 3 different tables
TABLE : ATTRIBUTE DEFINITION

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Email |
| 14 | Phone |
| 15 | AGE |
| 52 | MODE |
| 64 | member |

TABLE: ATTRIBUTE

| memberID | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28362836 | 12 | ..@.com |
| 28362836 | 52 | 1 |
| 28362836 | 15 | 12 |
| 28362836 | 64 | 2 |
| 28816936 | 54 | 9 |
| 28816936 | 64 | 7 |
| 39273734 | 12 | ..@.com |
| 39273734 | 64 | 5 |
| 39273734 | 64 | 4 |
| 73537282 | 52 | 4 |
| 82638191 | 14 | 9865... |
| 82638191 | 52 | 6 |
| 82638191 | 52 | 9 |
| 75719616 | 15 | 17 |
| 98272927 | 15 | 20 |
| 92726182 | 15 | 13 |
| 52825278 | 15 | 56 |

```
ID int 
MEMBERID INT
ATTRIBUTE VARCHAR 
VALUE VARCHAR 
T TIME INT
```

I have a table similar to this and I need to do something like

```
If Email = is valid '%@%.%' and Mode = 1 then update member = 5 

If Email = is valid  and mode = 4 then update member = 1

If phone like '9%' and  mode = 6 the member = 1

If Age = 56 then member = 2
```

Then all this needs to be insert into the table log using the member ID, Name, the oldvalue and the newvalue.
I am using a pivot for this but I am trying to find the out what the best approach could be.
table: Log

| memberID | attribute | oldvalue | updateV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28362836 | mode | 2 | 9 |

Then this table would update the real table

| memberID | Value | t |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28362836 | 2 | 4 |

After update

| memberID | Value | t |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28362836 | 9 | 4 |

This have to be done to all the condition and change different values from the same column.

```
WITH PAL AS (
  SELECT memeberID, email, phone
      AGE, MODE, member
   FROM 
    (SELECT memberID, name, value
      FROM ATTRIBUTEDEFINITION as d
      JOIN ATTRIBUTE AS a
         ON d.ID = a.ID
  ) e
   PIVOT
   ( MAX(Value) FROM Name IN
      (Email, phone, Age, mode, 
     member) piv 
  WHERE AGE between 0 AND 120)
```

```
   INSERT INTO log
     SELECT
      Pal.MEMBERID, a.ID, d.NAME, 
        OLDVALUE = pal.MEMEBER, 
         NEWVALUE = CASE
       WHEN Email = is valid '%@%.%' 
        and Mode = 1 then 5 
       WHEN Email = is valid 
        and mode = 4 then 1
       WHEN phone like '9%' 
        and  mode = 6 then = 1
       WHEN Age = 56 then 2 FROM PAL 
    JOIN ATTRIBUTEDEFINITION as d
       ON PAL.ID = d.ID
          JOIN ATTRIBUTE AS a
             ON d.ID = a.ID
         WHERE d.name = 'memeber'
```

Is there a better way to get the names and
the values to be able to use it with a case
statement of a better way to solve this. I
would appreciate some help. There is way more requirements meaning I will have to do the
same for Age and phone not just memeber that
why I am trying to get one where I can use
all of them.

Comment: What is the question here? Your syntax is a bit wrong in some places, but I think your method will generally work. Are you looking for alternate methods or are you looking for help with specific errors?

Comment: The table design in your question is an example of the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) antipattern, which as you point out makes it very difficult if not impossible to make good use of a relational DBMS. Is the "any" table something you're forced to work with, or do you have the option to replace it with a more normalized design?

Comment: I need to work with those tables as they were created before me. I am trying to figure out how to separate the the attribute values and connect them with the other values on the same row.  I been thinking about dynamic pivot but I am not very familiarize with it.

Comment: I am looking for alternate methods to fine a solution.

Comment: @Jojo, there are some inconsistencies between the structure of your tables and your SQL samples that make it difficult to understand exactly what is going on. You say these tables exist and that you have to work with them as they are, so could you please edit your question to reflect the current, complete table structure and queries that actually work with them?

Comment: I just update it